# Py2App PIL Image error when launching app

Tags: python, py2app

I am using py2app to convert a python file into an application and am running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/webstuff/BotTest/dist/ws1.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 87, in _recipes_pil_prescript
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/webstuff/BotTest/dist/ws1.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 132, in <module>
    _recipes_pil_prescript(['ImtImagePlugin', 'XpmImagePlugin', 'FtexImagePlugin', 'McIdasImagePlugin', 'MpegImagePlugin', 'SpiderImagePlugin', 'DdsImagePlugin', 'FpxImagePlugin', 'MspImagePlugin', 'XVThumbImagePlugin', 'GbrImagePlugin', 'MpoImagePlugin', 'BmpImagePlugin', 'BlpImagePlugin', 'IptcImagePlugin', 'PpmImagePlugin', 'JpegImagePlugin', 'SgiImagePlugin', 'PalmImagePlugin', 'PsdImagePlugin', 'ImImagePlugin', 'MicImagePlugin', 'BufrStubImagePlugin', 'WebPImagePlugin', 'FliImagePlugin', 'TgaImagePlugin', 'PixarImagePlugin', 'TiffImagePlugin', 'CurImagePlugin', 'PngImagePlugin', 'FitsStubImagePlugin', 'Hdf5StubImagePlugin', 'DcxImagePlugin', 'IcnsImagePlugin', 'EpsImagePlugin', 'GifImagePlugin', 'SunImagePlugin', 'WmfImagePlugin', 'GribStubImagePlugin', 'PcdImagePlugin', 'IcoImagePlugin', 'XbmImagePlugin', 'PdfImagePlugin', 'PcxImagePlugin', 'Jpeg2KImagePlugin'])
  File "/Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/webstuff/BotTest/dist/ws1.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 90, in _recipes_pil_prescript
    from PIL import Image
  File "PIL/Image.pyc", line 64, in <module>
  File "PIL/_imaging.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "PIL/_imaging.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/webstuff/BotTest/dist/ws1.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libjpeg.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/MYUSER/PycharmProjects/webstuff/BotTest/dist/ws1.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: image not found
```

After the error, the program is terminated. All images used in the program are included in it using data_files in the setup. Is there an error with my code or is it something to do with py2app?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Having the same problem now.

Answer (score 5):

In your

```
python setup.py py2app
```

or

```
python3 setup.py py2app
```

include the flag `--packages=PIL`

Answer (score 1):

Installing the dynamic library for `libpeg`

```
brew install libjpeg
```

should solve this, I still ran into other dependencies such as `zlib` and `openjpeg` however. But compiling Pillow myself worked.

```
git clone git@github.com:python-pillow/Pillow.git
brew install jpeg
brew install openjpeg
brew install zlib
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
cd Pillow
python setup.py install
```

Here's the summary:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 7.2.0.dev0
platform     darwin 3.8.1 (v3.8.1:1b293b6006, Dec 18 2019, 14:08:53)
             [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- JPEG support available
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support available (2.3)
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT support not available
--- LIBTIFF support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS2 support available
*** WEBP support not available
*** WEBPMUX support not available
--- XCB (X protocol) support available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
```