# Py2app struggles with loading PIL's Image module

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, py2app

Compiling a .py file that requires pillow to .app with py2app works, but it raises:

```
Modules not found (conditional imports):
 * Image (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2app/recipes/PIL/prescript.py)
```

Then, when I try to start the app, it stops immediately and shows this:

```
Last login: Fri Jul  3 19:06:46 on ttys001
/Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar\ Resourcepack\ Generator\ \(Mac\)/dist/Avatar\ Resourcepack\ Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Avatar\ Resourcepack\ Creator ; exit;
macbook-air-jpc:~ Cedric$ /Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar\ Resourcepack\ Generator\ \(Mac\)/dist/Avatar\ Resourcepack\ Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Avatar\ Resourcepack\ Creator ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar Resourcepack Generator (Mac)/dist/Avatar Resourcepack Creator.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 89, in _recipes_pil_prescript
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar Resourcepack Generator (Mac)/dist/Avatar Resourcepack Creator.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 136, in <module>
    _recipes_pil_prescript(['GbrImagePlugin', 'MicImagePlugin', 'PalmImagePlugin', 'XpmImagePlugin', 'TgaImagePlugin', 'DcxImagePlugin', 'PsdImagePlugin', 'SgiImagePlugin', 'EpsImagePlugin', 'XbmImagePlugin', 'BlpImagePlugin', 'PixarImagePlugin', 'FliImagePlugin', 'DdsImagePlugin', 'GribStubImagePlugin', 'XVThumbImagePlugin', 'PngImagePlugin', 'GifImagePlugin', 'Jpeg2KImagePlugin', 'IptcImagePlugin', 'IcnsImagePlugin', 'BmpImagePlugin', 'MpoImagePlugin', 'PpmImagePlugin', 'BufrStubImagePlugin', 'FtexImagePlugin', 'WebPImagePlugin', 'TiffImagePlugin', 'MpegImagePlugin', 'MspImagePlugin', 'SpiderImagePlugin', 'ImImagePlugin', 'FpxImagePlugin', 'SunImagePlugin', 'Hdf5StubImagePlugin', 'CurImagePlugin', 'McIdasImagePlugin', 'PdfImagePlugin', 'FitsStubImagePlugin', 'WmfImagePlugin', 'PcxImagePlugin', 'IcoImagePlugin', 'ImtImagePlugin', 'JpegImagePlugin', 'PcdImagePlugin'])
  File "/Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar Resourcepack Generator (Mac)/dist/Avatar Resourcepack Creator.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 93, in _recipes_pil_prescript
    from PIL import Image
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "PIL/Image.pyc", line 94, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "PIL/_imaging.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "PIL/_imaging.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar Resourcepack Generator (Mac)/dist/Avatar Resourcepack Creator.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libjpeg.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Cedric/Desktop/Avatar Resourcepack Generator (Mac)/dist/Avatar Resourcepack Creator.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: image not found
2020-07-03 19:09:41.090 Avatar Resourcepack Creator[3073:100237] Avatar Resourcepack Creator Error
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

The issue seems to be that it doesn't find the Pillow module and can't import the Image module either.
Here is my setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Avatar Resourcepack Creator.py']
DATA_FILES = ["assets", "icons", "logs", "pack.mcmeta", "pack.png", "Sorts utilisés.txt"]
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options=dict(py2app=dict(iconfile='icons/icon.ico', includes="tkinter, PIL, zipfile, os, getpass")),
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=['pillow'],
)
```

This has been driving me mad, as I've searched everywhere on the internet but didn't find anything.
Please help!

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690402/py2app-pil-image-error-when-launching-app.  Did any of the suggestions in that thread help you?

Comment: You may also find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141863/py2app-placing-pil-dylibs-in-zip-file/62164220#62164220